# Find the minimum value of $n$ such that $\sin^n(c)<\varepsilon$ for some small constant $\varepsilon>0$

Tags: trigonometry, asymptotics, computer-science

Let $c$ be a constant such that $0 <c \le \pi/2$ and $\sin(c) \ne 0$.

*Question*: What is the minimum value of $n$ such that $\sin^n(c)< \varepsilon$ for some small constant $\varepsilon >0$ ?

For example, let $c=1$ then $\sin(1)= 0.841, \sin^2(1)=0.708, \sin^4(1)=0.501,..., \sin^{20}(1)=0.0316$.

It is clear that $\sin^n(c)$ converges to $0$ as $n$ increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterated sine
(just search for it
and you will find,
for example,
this:
http://web.abo.fi/fak/mnf/mate/kurser/dynsyst/Iteration%20of%20sin(x).pdf)
satisfies
$\sin^{(n)}(x)
\approx \sqrt{\frac{3}{n}}
$.

Therefore,
you want
$\sqrt{\frac{3}{n}}
< \epsilon
$
or
$n 
>\frac{3}{\epsilon^2}
$.

Note that $x$ does not really come 
into this,
because, after a few iterations,
any dependence on $x$ goes away.

Comment: This question seems to be about $(\sin x)^n$ rather than the iterated sine.  (I thought it was about the iterated sine as well).

Comment: I think you are right, as $\sin^{(20)}(1) = 0.3551$ and $(\sin(1))^{20} = 0.0316$. But, I was credited with the answer. Oh well, I have been given points for a wrong answer in the past. Also, $\sqrt{3/20} \sim 0.387$ which is not far from $0.3551$.

Answer (score 1):

The logarithmic function is strictly increasing, so $\sin^n(c)<\epsilon$ exactly when $\ln(\sin^n(c))<\ln(\epsilon)$, which gives us
$$n\ln(\sin(c))<\ln(\epsilon)$$
Now, since $0<c\le\pi/2$, it follows that $0<\sin(c)\le1$.  We will consider two cases:
1)Suppose $\sin(c)=1$ $(c=\pi/2).$  Then we have a problem, since $1^n=1$, which will not be less than $\epsilon<1$.

2) Suppose that $\sin(c)<1$.  Then $\ln(\sin(c))<0$.  Thus, dividing this from the above equation gives us
$$n>\frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(\sin(c))}$$